# Use layout.ejs dynamic or how to edit a view-layout.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs, sails.io.js

Every Page which will be included in the layout.ejs has a view-pagename.js so I can use dynamic content in it.
How can I bring dynamic content a a default function to the layout page? There is no view-layout.js

Comment: Could you explain more clearly, please? If you are trying to set a variable to the layout, i.e. `Copyright <%= year %>` or what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I want to use variables in the layout.ejs which are not from sails config files (i.e. sails.config.custom.baseUrl) , I will use data from datastore (i.e. <%= pageTitle %>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `hooks` where you can get data from helpers or even from models. Check the routes helper specification:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/hook-specification/routes

So you can specify a hook using `sails generate hook some-hook-name` and use it:

```js
module.exports = function (sails) {
  return {

    initialize: function(cb) {
      sails.log.info('Hook some-hook-name loaded successfully');
    },

    routes: {
      before: {
        'GET /*': async function (req, res, next) {
          res.locals.pageTitle = await sails.helpers.getPageTitle(req);
          
          return next();
        }
      },
    }
  };
};
```

After that you can use it at the views:

```html
<%= pageTitle %>
```

And there is an example to set variables as locals:

https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/api/hooks/custom/index.js#L240